# Erro com Javascript do fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, console, fullcalendar, importação

Estou tentando importar o [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) em um projeto, estou usando o [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) para automatizar as importações. Porém quando coloco o caminho para importar o [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) me deparo com esse erro no console:

> **fullcalendar.min.js:6Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

O que pode ser o problema?

*Arquivo do `gulp`:*

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.styles([
        './resources/assets/css/app.css',
        './bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.print.min.css',
        './bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css',
    ]);
    mix.scripts([
        './bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        './node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
        './resources/assets/js/mask.js',
        './bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js',
        './resources/assets/js/app.js'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: tente alterar a ordem de declaração dos scripts, as vezes um está em conflito com o outro, pode tentar também remover todos e tentar incluir um por um